# USB Debugging on Galaxy Nexus causes Windows 7 to freeze

Tags: android, adb

G'day,
 When I have my Galaxy Nexus plugged in for morethan about 5 minutes with USB debugging on, Windows completely freezes – the last ~1 second of sound is looped throught the speakers, the laser in my mouse goes off, and it completely dies; the only way to 'fix' it is to do a hard reboot. I've looked around the web but I haven't found any (working) solutions. I've tried various different drivers, using "the right cable", and so on.
If you have any suggestions, that'd be great.
Cheers

EDIT: I've found and looked through a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24171&q=freeze%20windows%207&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) reported on the Android bug page, but nothing there is working for me, and the PC is Windows 7 64-bit

EDIT 2: I thought I'd fixed the problem by wiping the SDK off my computer then reinstalling the entire thing. This seemed to work for a while but then it did eventually freeze.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other android devices?

Comment: nope, Nexus One, Transformer, and Incredible S all work fine. ADB also recognises the Galaxy Nexus and I can install apps to it and debug etc. it just freezes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had my Galaxy Nexus plugged in with USB Debugging on for about 12 hours now, and the solution seems to have been *not* to use a **USB 3.0** port – I plugged the phone in through a USB (2.0) hub on the side of my monitor and it's going great.

Hope that helps anyone else with this problem.